# Character Counter with a switch statement java

Tags: java, character, switch-statement, counter

I'm writing a character counter programme which reads a line of text and counts the number of vowels, consonant, spaces and punctuation.

I also have to use a switch to increment the count of each.  As it's the first time I've used a switch statement in a programme, I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly within the loop.

As far as I can work out, the issue is with the loop as it compiles, but when it runs, it hangs in the terminal, so I'm assuming the loop is not terminating correctly.

I know my methods of counting the characters are very basic, but that is as per the 
instructions.

Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class CharacterCounter2
{
public static void main(String args[])
{

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = new String(scan.nextLine());

String cons = new String ("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz");
String vowels = new String ("aeiou");
String space = new String (" ");
String punct = new String(",.;:");

int consCount = 0, vowelCount = 0, spaceCount = 0, pCount = 0, inx = 0;
char ch = line.charAt(inx);

while (inx <= line.length()-1)

{
if (cons.indexOf(line.charAt(inx)) != -1)
ch = 'C';
else 
if (vowels.indexOf(line.charAt(inx)) != -1)
ch = 'V';
else
if(line.equals(space))
ch = 'S';
if (punct.indexOf(line.charAt(inx)) != -1)
ch = 'P';

switch (ch)
{
case 'C':
consCount += 1;
break;

case 'V':
vowelCount += 1;
break;

case 'S':
spaceCount += 1;
break;

case 'P':
pCount += 1;

default:
break;

}

inx = inx ++;
ch = line.charAt(inx);
}



System.out.println("contains" +consCount+" consonants, "+vowelCount+" vowels, " + spaceCount+" spaces" + pCount + "punctuation");
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't ever want to write this:

```
inx = inx ++;
```

what you mean is simply

```
inx++;
```

That should at least get the loop to terminate, otherwise I think it might work except your space counting logic is wrong.

Comment: The reason why inx = inx++ is wrong is due to the definition of inx++. It has a side effect of incrementing inx, but its value, the value that will be assigned to inx, is the old value.

Comment: ah, an obvious mistake! I hadn't worked on it any java for a few weeks.  Thanks so much, will give it a go!